build localized variant applications using ngx-translate (migrate ngx-translate to angular i18n)
So currently our Angular project uses the ngx-translate package to internationalize it.
we have the directory src/assets/i18n/ containns ws-en.json, ws-fr.json and ws-de.json
The problem: I want to write some script that uses the current translation method to build the application for each language;
the Angular i18n is really helpful but is there a way to use ngx-translate package and adapt the native angular package to it.
or maybe write xlf files from the ngx-translate assets.
